# conda update/install now comes with a load of text in my terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, anaconda, conda

On Xubuntu, as of my last update of conda (now on 4.1.8), updating or installing packages comes with a huge dump of text in my terminal that I haven't seen before. It does work as expected, but it is quite annoying. Does anyone know why this happens?

```
me@mymachine:~$ conda update --all
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata ...INFO:stdoutlog:Fetching package metadata ...
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.continuum.io
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.continuum.io
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.continuum.io
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.continuum.io
.DEBUG:dotupdate:fetching repodata: args ('https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/',) kwargs {'session': <conda.connection.CondaSession object at 0x7fea2e0fef98>, 'use_cache': False}
.DEBUG:dotupdate:fetching repodata: args ('https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/',) kwargs {'session': <conda.connection.CondaSession object at 0x7fea2e0fea58>, 'use_cache': False}
.DEBUG:dotupdate:fetching repodata: args ('https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/',) kwargs {'session': <conda.connection.CondaSession object at 0x7fea2e144208>, 'use_cache': False}
.DEBUG:dotupdate:fetching repodata: args ('https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/',) kwargs {'session': <conda.connection.CondaSession object at 0x7fea2e0fe4a8>, 'use_cache': False}

INFO:stdoutlog:

Solving package specifications: INFO:stdoutlog:Solving package specifications: 
.DEBUG:dotupdate:Solving for [MatchSpec('libsodium'), MatchSpec('multipledispatch'), MatchSpec('rope'), MatchSpec('jdcal'), MatchSpec('cffi'), MatchSpec('bottleneck'), MatchSpec('anaconda-client'), MatchSpec('sqlite'), MatchSpec('click'), MatchSpec('python-dateutil'), MatchSpec('lxml'), MatchSpec('pyyaml'), MatchSpec('pixman'), MatchSpec('pyproj'), MatchSpec('toolz'), MatchSpec('scikit-learn'), MatchSpec('nose'), MatchSpec('shapely'), MatchSpec('cloudpickle'), MatchSpec('docutils'), MatchSpec('psutil'), MatchSpec('libtiff'), MatchSpec('nbconvert'), MatchSpec('pycosat'), MatchSpec('sqlalchemy'), MatchSpec('sip'), MatchSpec('ply'), MatchSpec('system'), MatchSpec('partd'), MatchSpec('proj.4'), MatchSpec('spyder-app'), MatchSpec('ipywidgets'), MatchSpec('pyflakes'), MatchSpec('qtconsole'), MatchSpec('six'), MatchSpec('conda'), MatchSpec('krb5'), MatchSpec('backports'), MatchSpec('harfbuzz'), MatchSpec('werkzeug'), MatchSpec('markupsafe'), MatchSpec('theano'), MatchSpec('matplotlib'), MatchSpec('ipython-qtconsole'), MatchSpec('redis'), MatchSpec('pillow'), MatchSpec('pandas'), MatchSpec('libdynd'), MatchSpec('simplegeneric'), MatchSpec('get_terminal_size'), MatchSpec('pytest'), MatchSpec('glib'), MatchSpec('et_xmlfile'), MatchSpec('cartopy'), MatchSpec('sympy'), MatchSpec('snowballstemmer'), MatchSpec('jupyter_core'), MatchSpec('ipykernel'), MatchSpec('tornado'), MatchSpec('sphinx'), MatchSpec('dynd-python'), MatchSpec('pycparser'), MatchSpec('statsmodels'), MatchSpec('ipython-notebook'), MatchSpec('curl'), MatchSpec('locket'), MatchSpec('libgfortran'), MatchSpec('wheel'), MatchSpec('seaborn'), MatchSpec('mistune'), MatchSpec('jupyter'), MatchSpec('libnetcdf'), MatchSpec('sphinx_rtd_theme'), MatchSpec('argcomplete'), MatchSpec('odo'), MatchSpec('pycrypto'), MatchSpec('tk'), MatchSpec('beautifulsoup4'), MatchSpec('requests'), MatchSpec('conda-env'), MatchSpec('cycler'), MatchSpec('flask-cors'), MatchSpec('scikit-image'), MatchSpec('bitarray'), MatchSpec('anaconda'), MatchSpec('cython'), MatchSpec('sas7bdat'), MatchSpec('chest'), MatchSpec('ptyprocess'), MatchSpec('jupyter_console'), MatchSpec('hdf5'), MatchSpec('readline'), MatchSpec('protobuf'), MatchSpec('tensorflow'), MatchSpec('notebook'), MatchSpec('numpy'), MatchSpec('nbformat'), MatchSpec('pyopenssl'), MatchSpec('idna'), MatchSpec('fastcache'), MatchSpec('ipython_genutils'), MatchSpec('libxml2'), MatchSpec('jbig'), MatchSpec('entrypoints'), MatchSpec('pytz'), MatchSpec('abstract-rendering'), MatchSpec('bokeh'), MatchSpec('owslib'), MatchSpec('networkx'), MatchSpec('zeromq'), MatchSpec('scipy'), MatchSpec('openssl'), MatchSpec('libxslt'), MatchSpec('cryptography'), MatchSpec('xz'), MatchSpec('yaml'), MatchSpec('zlib'), MatchSpec('alabaster'), MatchSpec('_license'), MatchSpec('pyshp'), MatchSpec('cytoolz'), MatchSpec('colorama'), MatchSpec('prompt_toolkit'), MatchSpec('patsy'), MatchSpec('astropy'), MatchSpec('basemap'), MatchSpec('fontconfig'), MatchSpec('dask'), MatchSpec('pyparsing'), MatchSpec('wcwidth'), MatchSpec('imagesize'), MatchSpec('configobj'), MatchSpec('pygments'), MatchSpec('pytables'), MatchSpec('qt'), MatchSpec('pbr'), MatchSpec('sockjs-tornado'), MatchSpec('libpng'), MatchSpec('h5py'), MatchSpec('pycurl'), MatchSpec('libffi'), MatchSpec('heapdict'), MatchSpec('jpeg'), MatchSpec('spyder'), MatchSpec('util-linux'), MatchSpec('pango'), MatchSpec('ujson'), MatchSpec('pep8'), MatchSpec('pyepsg'), MatchSpec('xlrd'), MatchSpec('traitlets'), MatchSpec('unicodecsv'), MatchSpec('path.py'), MatchSpec('pyzmq'), MatchSpec('cairo'), MatchSpec('setuptools'), MatchSpec('blaze'), MatchSpec('graphviz'), MatchSpec('python'), MatchSpec('greenlet'), MatchSpec('terminado'), MatchSpec('redis-py'), MatchSpec('openblas'), MatchSpec('pexpect'), MatchSpec('conda-build'), MatchSpec('babel'), MatchSpec('pickleshare'), MatchSpec('xlsxwriter'), MatchSpec('ruamel_yaml'), MatchSpec('patchelf'), MatchSpec('netcdf4'), MatchSpec('jedi'), MatchSpec('mkl'), MatchSpec('nltk'), MatchSpec('jupyter_client'), MatchSpec('itsdangerous'), MatchSpec('ipython'), MatchSpec('flask'), MatchSpec('line_profiler'), MatchSpec('pip'), MatchSpec('numexpr'), MatchSpec('freetype'), MatchSpec('jsonschema'), MatchSpec('decorator'), MatchSpec('openpyxl'), MatchSpec('clyent'), MatchSpec('pyasn1'), MatchSpec('mock'), MatchSpec('datashape'), MatchSpec('llvmlite'), MatchSpec('geos'), MatchSpec('xlwt'), MatchSpec('mpmath'), MatchSpec('py'), MatchSpec('boto'), MatchSpec('pyqt'), MatchSpec('blaze-core'), MatchSpec('jinja2'), MatchSpec('numba'), MatchSpec('python 3.5* (target=python-3.5.0rc4-0.tar.bz2)')]
.DEBUG:dotupdate:Checking satisfiability
.DEBUG:dotupdate:Package removal metric: 0
.DEBUG:dotupdate:Initial package version/build metrics: 17/5
.DEBUG:dotupdate:Track feature count: 0
.DEBUG:dotupdate:Package feature count: 0
.DEBUG:dotupdate:Dependency update count: 0
.DEBUG:dotupdate:Additional package version/build metrics: 0/0
.DEBUG:dotupdate:Weak dependency count: 0
.DEBUG:dotupdate:Looking for alternate solutions

INFO:stdoutlog:


# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/marcel/anaconda3:
#
```

Then follows the usual list of packages. The text above is what bothers me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have this problem too.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when conda-build `1.21.8` or `1.21.9` is installed.  To fix, you can back up to `1.21.7` or update to `1.21.10` which should be available soon.

Comment: That fixed things indeed. Thanks for taking the time to point out my impatience :)